# Is the inequality $\left| \cos(n^8) + \sin(3n+8) \right| \leq 2$ true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am studying the convergence of a sum and by using absolute convergence I am trying to "shrink" it to use direct comparison test.

But this $ \left| \cos(n^8) + \sin(3n+8) \right| $ factor appears and I am wondering if  $ \left| \cos(n^8) + \sin(3n+8) \right| \leq 2$

Note that $n \to \infty$

It makes sense to me because sin and cos are bounded by one, therefore their sum cannot be greater than 2. But on the other hand writing $ \left| \cos(n^8) + \sin(3n+8) \right| = \left| \cos(n^8) \right| + \left|\sin(3n+8) \right| \leq 1+1=2 $ is not true because you cannot break the absolute like that.

So I am wondering, does this inequality actually hold (I am almost sure it does) and how to actually prove it **algebraically**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowed to break the absolute value by using the [Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

In particular:

$$|\cos(n^2)+\sin(n+2)|\le |\cos (n^2)| + |\sin(n+2)| \le 1+1=2$$

Comment: Thank you @player3236. I'll accept you answer in 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$-1\le \cos(n^8)  \le 1 \quad \land \quad -1\le  \sin(3n+8) \le 1$$

and therefore

$$-2\le \cos(n^8) + \sin(3n+8) \le 2 \iff \left| \cos(n^8) + \sin(3n+8) \right| \leq 2$$